# How to convert Datetime to Date in JPA query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm writing complicated queries using Spring data JPA, let's say a statistics query.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StatisticsPair {
  private LocalDateTime time;
  private BigDecimal balance;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="t_order")
public class Order {
  private LocalDateTime createdTime;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private OrderStatus status;
}
```

query in a repository:

```
@Query("select new xxx.StatisticsPair(createdTime, sum(amount)) from Order where createdTime >= ?1 and createdTime <= ?2 and status = xxx.OrderStatus.COMPLETED group by createdTime")
List<StatisticsPair> statAmountByDay(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

method `statAmountByDay` gives me a result like:

```
[
  {"time": "2006-01-02 15:04:05", "balance": 100.00}
  {"time": "2006-01-02 16:04:05", "balance": 200.00}
  {"time": "2006-01-03 15:04:05", "balance": 200.00}
]
```

but I want statistics by day, only need date, time is useless, expected result:

```
[
  {"time": "2006-01-02", "balance": 300.00}
  {"time": "2006-01-03", "balance": 200.00}
]
```

so I want to know how to convert `createdTime`(datetime type) to `Date` type, like function `DATE(createdTime)` in mysql, but I don't wanna use native query, because my code runs on different ENV, use different databases.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the best way to do it, but until I find a better solution, you can manipulate the returned time as a String (using [SUBSTRING](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#SUBSTRING___Getting_a_Portion_of_a_String_))

`xxx.StatisticsPair(substring(cast(createdTime as nvarchar(19)), 1, 10), sum(amount))`

or try:

`xxx.StatisticsPair(cast(createdTime as date), sum(amount))`

Comment: Inspired by you, it now works, but I'm still looking for a graceful way, I think may be SpEL can help.

`
@Query("select new xxx.StatisticsPair(createdTime, sum(amount)) from Order where createdTime >= ?1 and createdTime <= ?2 and status = xxx.OrderStatus.COMPLETED group by substring(createdTime, 0, 10)")
`

Though the result `time` field contains time info, but I can deal with after query.

Comment: sorry about the style,  stackoverflow's markdown in comment is awful.

Comment: 2 things to say. First is you can try the conversion to date, as I mentioned in an edit. Second is if you think my answer is right, then could you please accept it?

Comment: conversion doesn't work, it's an illegalArgumentException, but `substring` works in `group by` clause, that's the import thing, gives me correct result, I'm still looking for better way.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible solutions:

1. Change LocalDateTime in object StatisticsPair to have LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime and hopefully spring JPA will take only the date component:

....

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StatisticsPair {
    private LocalDate date;
    private BigDecimal balance;
}
```

2. Second solution is to manipulate with java and java streams over the list of StatisticsPair:

....

```
List<StatisticsPair> list = ... ;
List<StatisticsPairWithDate> listWithDate;
listWithDate = list
            .stream()
            .map(sp-> 
                    new StatisticsPairWithDate(
                            sp.getTime().toLocalDate(), 
                            sp.getBalance()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

....

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StatisticsPairWithDate {
  private LocalDate date;
  private BigDecimal balance;
}
```

=============================================

```
@Query("select new xxx.StatisticsPair(createdTime, sum(amount)) from Order where createdTime >= ?1 and createdTime <= ?2 and status = xxx.OrderStatus.COMPLETED group by createdTime")
List<StatisticsPair> statAmountByDay(LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, it's not about result, it's about parameters which I pass into database.

For the result `2006-01-02 15:04:05` and `2006-01-02` both can map to `LocalDateTime` .

Comment: Just you can use LocalDate as parameter. JPA engine should take care of the rest.

Comment: See the last update on the bottom, just change the parameters, JPA will handle this.